# Why Java interfaces have descriptions in docs

Tags: java, syntax, interface

I know that an interface has only method declarations inside it and the implementations for them are provided only when some classes are implementing an interface (I am not talking about default methods or functional interfaces).

The question is: why do Java docs, turorials, books or other sources of information provide descriptions for the interfaces' methods? For example, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/List.html provides a full description of the `List` interface methods, but if it is only an interface then those methods should not provide any functionality, so what is described in these docs, then?

Comment: If there were no docs, how would I know what behaviour to expect if I had a `List`?

Comment: You mean: what that method SHOULD do if it was implemented?

Comment: Well, I was thinking pretty the same thing, but it looked kind of too abstract

Comment: as you already know interface is used to communicate from one class to another class. So interface are created for communication between two classes whose communication methods are already defined inside this interface which is **unique**. it means if an interface defines some methods from it can be used only with those classes which require them. e.g. I want to search something then i can use google (interface to search) or yahoo (interface to search) or bing (again interface to search). good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description is the goal of the interface object and his methods, if there is no description you will not know how to write in your method when you implement this interface object.

For example what does the method void clear()?

option 1) remove all the objects

option 2) remove your last insert to list

option 3) remove duplicates objects

and so on..

Of course this is an easy example and you can guess that the goal of clear() is option 1 but sometimes it's much more complicated.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it seems the clearest to me and also the example is very clear. But I liked @KrishPrabakar answer too because of its references to Effective Java. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have to clearly specify the motivation behind the interface and what the contract is for callers and implementors.

That said, comments in interfaces are for two audiences: callers and implementers. Both should be aware what they can expect, how they should behave.

And obviously just like normal classes, docs in interfaces should adhere to the standard, JavaDoc's rules.

Answer (score 1):

## Joshua Bloch (Effective Java) - If an API is to be usable, it must be documented

Unless you document your interface methods, others (API users) will not know about -

1. What it does (not *How* it does)
2. Its *preconditions*
3. Its *postconditions*
4. Its *side effects*
5. Its *Thread safety*

#### Effective Java - Item 44 says:

> The doc comment for a method should describe succinctly the contract
>   between the method and its client.

---

There's an additional advantage documenting interface methods:  **Inheritance** using `{@inheritDoc}`.

#### Effective Java - Item 44 says:

> Javadoc has the ability to “inherit” method comments. If an API
>   element does not have a doc comment, Javadoc searches for the most
>   specific applicable doc comment, giving preference to interfaces over
>   superclasses. The details of the search algorithm can be found in The
>   Javadoc Reference Guide [Javadoc-ref]. You can also inherit parts of
>   doc comments from supertypes using the  {@inheritDoc} tag. This means,
>   among other things, that classes can reuse doc comments from
>   interfaces they implement, rather than copying these comments. This
>   facility has the potential to reduce the burden of maintaining
>   multiple sets of nearly identical doc comments

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Because, we need javadoc for interfaces for **providing information** to Java developer who implements these interface(s).